# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: dart, flutter

I left my flutter project for a while when Flutter beta v1.0.0 was out. Now I moved my project to a new system with latest Flutter (stable v1.2.1) and Dart and ran into this build exception problem.

Note this project is working fine on my old desktop
flutter doctor output below

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

flutter doctor output of new/current system

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.32.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

pubsec.yaml

[gist link to pubsec.yaml](https://gist.github.com/purplecandy/b20eda67346de40fe58acb58dbb315f5#file-pubsec-ymal)

Since I'm coming back after a long time I have no idea what changes Flutter went through can anyone please help me out

Output of flutter run on current system

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.5s
Resolving dependencies...                                           6.0s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:956: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:957: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\18c59619c56cba96590906f3917a302b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\powerpurple\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.codee\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0-rc01.aar\353a670f458ae84ffafa8b187ee27491\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\f099bdc17ba82cfe6a5a3ab5ab60bee4\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\f099bdc17ba82cfe6a5a3ab5ab60bee4\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\18c59619c56cba96590906f3917a302b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\powerpurple\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.codee\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
PS D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                           5.7s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:956: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:957: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\18c59619c56cba96590906f3917a302b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\powerpurple\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.codee\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0-rc01.aar\353a670f458ae84ffafa8b187ee27491\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\f099bdc17ba82cfe6a5a3ab5ab60bee4\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\f099bdc17ba82cfe6a5a3ab5ab60bee4\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\powerpurple\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\18c59619c56cba96590906f3917a302b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\powerpurple\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.codee\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          D:\Android Projects\maze-flutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        19.6s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See * for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you using any firebase dependencies? Could you add your `pubspec.yaml', dependencies section to your question?

Comment: @R.Duggan no I don't have any firebase question. Also I have updated the question

Comment: @R.Duggan found same issue with firebase. Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The missing resources were only added in API 28. You need to update your `compileSDKversio`n in your `build.gradle` file to version 28.

Comment: how do you get to know about these? like seriously im curious.

Comment: A big hint was that they were referenced in "values-v28" (API 28+). You can check out AOSP source code and see where they were added.

Comment: you save my life!

Comment: Thank you!
In my case, after changing the compiledSdkVersion, I had to change the GradleException to Exception in the next line:
`throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")`

Comment: you saved hours :)

Answer (score 3):

`compileSdkVersion` update worked for me!
**/AppName/android/app/build.gradle** 
adnroid **`compileSdkVersion: 28`** to **`compileSdkVersion: 30`**

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Android emulator **API 30**
Dart 2.10.2
Flutter 1.22.2

Answer (score 2):

Go to  /AppName/android/app/build.gradle
in defaultConfig update both to

```
    compileSdkVersion 31
    targetSdkVersion 31
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

add this line in **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```