# I´m getting this error "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'" on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sdk

I´m using flutter version 3.4.0 with cloud_firestore version ^4.1.0 and I´m getting this error:
`Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore]`

How should I change version of the minSdk from 16 to 19?

This is my defaultConfig:
`

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line into your `local_properties` :

`flutter.minSdkVersion=21`

Then in your `build.gradle` under the app folder find the `defaultConfig` and replace value of `minSdkVersion` for `localProperties.getProperty(‘flutter.minSdkVersion’).toInteger()`

To finish just type commands `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify it in your `build.gradle` file.
see: [Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343843/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources)

Hope it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).